# Webview doesn't start from 0dp on left

Tags: android, webview

Hi All,

I have a web-view in my application which displays some text with justification.Everything seems to be perfect but i have a small issue with it which is shown in below fig.
[image]

The January starts right below the Month,26-01-2012 starts right below the date but webview starts by leaving a 1 dp space.

My code for the webview is

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:background="@drawable/bl"
         />
```

I need the webview right under the description.Can i achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your full layout.

Comment: post the full layout xml , i think somewhere in your xml code , you have some margin , and if not , add this to your WebView tag : android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"

Comment: try negative layout margins on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this..

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the your coding right , spacing of 1 dp as you say is leaving because there is font size are different for those texts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading only webview then instead of webview from xml try below code::

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
```

Comment: I am loading textviews and imageviews with webview.

Comment: the paste your complete xml file